# Laravel tests database migration from schema

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, testing, laravel-8

## The problem

- I am using Laravel `8.83.23`
- I have schema dump from squashed migrations in `database\schema\mysql-schema.dump`
- tests are running above test database, as in `database.php`

```
    'testing' => [
                    'driver' => 'mysql',
                    'host' => env('DB_TEST_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('DB_TEST_PORT', '3306'),
                    'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                    'username' => env('DB_TEST_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                    'password' => env('DB_TEST_PASSWORD', ''),
                ],
```

- Before I squashed migrations, my test cases only used `DatabaseMigrations` trait, and the test database was recreated every time and all worked, example of test class:

```
    class SystemControllerTest extends TestCase
    {
        use WithFaker;
        use DatabaseMigrations;
        /**
         * @var User
         */
        private $user;
    
        public function setUp(): void
        {
            parent::setUp();
    
            //create roles and data
            $this->seed(RoleAndPermissionSeeder::class);
        ... etc
```

- the migrations were found and executed, recreating the database
- then, I squashed the migrations, so all migrations got deleted, and I got `database\schema\mysql-schema.dump`
- `php artisan migrate` works as expected through command line, creating full database schemas from the dump (it finds it)
- tests however no longer work, as there is an error

```
    SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cinema_test.roles' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `roles`)
```

- when I check the sql test database after the test runs, it is empty (only table `migrations` gets created there, and it is empty)
- this error persists even when I call `artisan migrate` in the test's setup:

```
    public function setUp(): void
        {
            parent::setUp();
            Artisan::call('migrate', array(
       '--database' => 'testing',
       '--force' => true));
            //it crashes here
            $this->seed(RoleAndPermissionSeeder::class);
```

- `RoleAndPermissionSeeder` just operates with the sql tables, which do not exist, hence the error
- I even tried `DatabaseMigrations` and `DatabaseTransactions` and `RefreshDatabase` traits, without any success
- how do I populate the database data? There is no way for me to read the output of the `Artisan::call('migrate')` command, so I do not know what is happening there
- return code of `Artisan::call('migrate')` is `0`
- is there maybe some setup I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured this out.

## The reason for the problem

The problem was in incorrect setup of the testing environment. I have not discovered the exact reason, but I figured out how to setup the testing environment so that the dump would be found and loaded.

## How I hunt down the bug

This describes my steps on how I found a way to fix this.

###### In `database.php` I have copied testing database instead of normal one

- in `database.php` I had the main database connection:

```
    'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => false,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
                ]) : [],
            ],
```

and the testing connection

```
    'testing' => [
                    'driver' => 'mysql',
                    'host' => env('DB_TEST_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('DB_TEST_PORT', '3306'),
                    'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                    'username' => env('DB_TEST_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                    'password' => env('DB_TEST_PASSWORD', ''),
                ],
```

- I copied the `testing` connection data into a new `mysql` connection, just to see, whether on a command line I get same results
- so, the file then looked like this

```
    'mysql' => [
                'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                    'host' => env('DB_TEST_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('DB_TEST_PORT', '3306'),
                    'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                    'username' => env('DB_TEST_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                    'password' => env('DB_TEST_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'prefix_indexes' => true,
                'strict' => false,
                'engine' => null,
                'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
                ]) : [],
            ],
    
    /*'testing' => [
                    'driver' => 'mysql',
                    'host' => env('DB_TEST_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('DB_TEST_PORT', '3306'),
                    'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                    'username' => env('DB_TEST_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                    'password' => env('DB_TEST_PASSWORD', ''),
                ],*/
```

- on the console, I ran `php artisan:migrate`
- the database dump was found and loaded
- therefore, the dump was found in normal cases, but was **not** found, in testing cases
- after some research, I changed the testing environment setup in `phpunit.xml`, I will explain it now

###### The file `phpunit.xml`

The `phpunit.xml` was as follows (not full file shown here):

```
       <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>     
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

- so, we can see that the testing database connection is defined for unit tests
- on web I found advice to set the database table only, instead of changing entire connection for tests, because it is easier
- I tried such an approach, so the `phpunit.xml` became

```
       <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="cinema_test"/>   
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

- I deleted the testing connection from `database.php` and related obsolete variables from `.env` file
- this fixed the issue, and the dump file got loaded even in tests now

###### Conclusion

Although I have not figured out the real cause for the lavavel not loading the dump file, I have found a workaround which was to only change the database name for tests, instead of defining entirely new sql connection for testing pursposes. This solved the issue, and the database dump file gets loaded during tests now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like schema dumps can't be used for the in-memory database when testing

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#squashing-migrations

May be able to do something like this

`DB::unprepared(file_get_contents("path/file.sql"));`

Would only try as a last resort, personally would want a test environment migration, also you should add a check for a test environment migration if you take this approach

Comment: Thank you for your insight. However, I believe the bug was somewhere is testing connection definition. I have posted an answer to this question for future visitors

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I was going off the details for Laravel 9, not 8